# How to use induction in this sense?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, induction

For context, I've learned induction before, in a different way than this author mentions, but I believe I understand it's a rephrasing of it. However, I have no idea how to apply it to these two problems in particular,

[image: Principle of Induction]

here is the definition of induction,

[image: Problem 1]

I attempted this problem first, but my technique is not correct

*Proof*:

Let $E=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid (x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_{n-1})+x_n=x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n\}$ then we want to show by induction that $E=\mathbb{N}$. Consider that $E\subset \mathbb{N}$ and that $x_1=x_1$ so $1\in E$. Now, assume that $k\in E$ then
\begin{align*}
        (x_1+\cdots +x_{k-1})+x_k=x_1+\cdots+x_k
    \end{align*}
furthermore consider the sum
\begin{align*}
        (x_1+\cdots + x_k)+x_{k+1}
    \end{align*}
then by associativity of the reals, we can achieve
\begin{align*}
        (x_1+\cdots+x_{k-1})+(x_{k}+x_{k+1})
        =x_1+\cdots+x_k+x_{k+1}
    \end{align*}
by the inductive hypothesis since $x_k+x_{k+1}$ is real therefore $E=\mathbb{N}$ and the sum $x_1+\cdots +x_n$ is defined independently of the insertion of parentheses.

However, this seems circular in some way; any suggestions on using this definition correctly and/or proving this statement by induction? Also, I think I missed a couple of cases regarding the bracket movements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a too weak induction hypothesis. Don't try to use $(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_{k-1})+ x_k$ and don't consider the numbers $x_i$ as fixed. By the way, in your definition of $E$, $(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_{n-1})+x_n=x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$ doesn't make sense.

Your hypothesis should be: for ANY $n$ numbers, ALL the possible insertion of parentheses yields the same result. In terms of sets it should be $E = \{ n\in \Bbb N \mid \text{ for all }x_1, x_2, \cdots x_n \in \Bbb R, \text{all the possible insertion of parentheses in } x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n \text{ yields the same result}\}$

Comment: Makes sense; any idea how I would go about the induction step then? I know that induction starts with $1\in E$, which is trivial, then assume for any $k\in E$ to show $k+1\in E$. Following that, I'd have to show for all $x_1$ up to $x_{k+1}$ that all possible parentheses insertion is the same, but this doesn't seem easy.